# Prevent drop if element exists in angular dragula

Tags: angularjs, dragula

I am using angularJs and angular-dragula.My application has a list of draggable items and i would like to prevent drop if there is already an element present at target location.

Thanku.

Comment: I think you may want something along the lines of drake.on('drop', (el, target) => { if (target.children.length) { drake.cancel(); } });